# Easy68k: How to call a macro in assembly?

Tags: assembly, macros, call, motorola, easy68k

I'm using easy68k for the first time, and I wrote two macros that I want to call in my program. The macro definitions compiled just fine.

However, when I try to call the macro from within the main program (i.e. after the "org" statement) it doesn't compile.

I tried all the syntax that I could think of, I checked the help section and a few other sites on the internet, and nothing worked.

Currently, when I compile the code below, it displays two error messages:

One says: Line 57 (MUL_MAC d1,d3,) ERROR: Invalid argument
The other says: Line 60 (bsr MUL_SUB) ERROR: Invalid argument

Here is my source code (MC68000 assembly):

```
MUL_MAC macro          
    movem.l d6-d7, -(a7)
    move.w \1, d6
    clr.l d7
loop\@ add.w \2, d7
    dbra d6, loop\@
    move.w d7, \2
    movem.l (a7)+, d6-d7
    endm

MUL_SUB equ *           ; Subroutine
    move.w d2, d3
    clr.l d4
loop_sub add.w d1, d4
    dbra d3, loop_sub
    move.w d4, d2
    rts

PRINT_RES macro         
    movem.l d5-d7, -(a7)
    clr.l a1
    move #248, d7   ; Code to display character
    cmp \1, \2
    beq right\@
    move.b INC_L, d5
loop_ch_2\@ move.b  INC(a1)+, d0
    trap #14
    dbra d5, loop_ch_2\@
    bra finish\@
right\@ move.b COR_L, d5
loop_ch_2\@ move.b  COR(a1)+, d0
    trap #14
    dbra d5, loop_ch_2\@
finish\@ movem.l (a7)+, d5-d7
    endm

    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

    clr.w d1
    clr.w d2
    clr.w d3
    clr.w d4

    move.w X, d1
    move.w Y, d2
    move.w d2, d3
    move.w d2, d4

    mulu d1, d4         ; Store the actual result in d2 to compare later
    MUL_MAC d1,d3,
    PRINT_RES d3,d4,

    bsr MUL_SUB
    PRINT_RES d2,d4,

    move #228, d7
    trap #14

* Put program code here

    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

* Put variables and constants here

X   ds  1
Y   ds  1
INC dc.b    73, 78, 67, 79, 82, 82, 69, 67, 84 ; INCORRECT
COR dc.b    67, 79, 82, 82, 69, 67, 84         ; CORRECT 
INC_L dc.b 9                                   ; Length of INCORRECT
COR_L dc.b 7                                   ; Length of CORRECT


    END    START        ; last line of source
```

Comment: Define _"doesn't compile"_. Do you get an error message? If so, exactly what does the message say?

Comment: That's a good point, I'm going to edit the post to include that, but basically it displays two error messages when I compile the above:

One says: Line 57 (MUL_MAC d1,d3,) ERROR: Invalid argument
The other says: Line 60 (bsr MUL_SUB) ERROR: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

At least I would remove the trailing commas like this

```
MUL_MAC d1,d3
PRINT_RES d3,d4
```